# Requesting sshPublicKey with ldapsearch failes

Tags: linux, ldap, openldap, ubuntu-20.04, ldap-query

I am currently trying to setup logon via LDAP on my Ubuntu 20.04 server. The login with the password already works but the login with the sshPublicKey returns the message `No such object (32)`.
With the logfiles and some research I could find out that the BIND dn is an empty string although it is specified differently in the ldap.conf file with the attribute rootbinddn. So you could login anonymously, but this was disabled on my openldap server and the admin accout should be used instead.

Am I missing something or why am I not able to get the sshPublicKey with this configuration?

/bin/ldap-keys.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
ldapsearch -LL -h ldap.mydomain.com \
-b "ou=users;dc=mydomain;dc=com" \
-x '(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid='"$1"'))' \
'sshPublicKey' \
| sed -n '/^ /{H;d};/sshPublicKey:/x;$g;s/\n *//g;s/sshPublicKey: //gp'
```

/etc/ldap/ldap.conf

```
base dc=mydomain,dc=com
uri ldaps://ldap.mydomain.com/
ldap_version 3
rootbinddn cn=admin,dc=mydomain,dc=com
pam_password md5
tls_checkpeer yes
```

OpenLDAP Log

```
openldap    | 60666a8f conn=1095 fd=21 ACCEPT from IP=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:30000 (IP=0.0.0.0:389)
openldap    | 60666a8f conn=1095 op=0 BIND dn="" method=128
openldap    | 60666a8f conn=1095 op=0 RESULT tag=97 err=0 text=
openldap    | 60666a8f conn=1095 op=1 SRCH base="ou=users,dc=mydomain,dc=com" scope=2 deref=0 filter="(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=USERNAME))"
openldap    | 60666a8f conn=1095 op=1 SRCH attr=sshPublicKey
openldap    | 60666a8f conn=1095 op=1 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=32 nentries=0 text=
openldap    | 60666a8f conn=1095 op=2 UNBIND
openldap    | 60666a8f conn=1095 fd=21 closed
```

Comment: Mmm.. looks like you should use `binddn` instead of `rootbinddn` (or /etc/ldap.secret is missing?)

Comment: I added `binddn cn=admin,dc=mydomain,dc=com` to /etc/ldap/ldap.conf but "BIND dn" is still empty in the log. /etc/ldap.secret exists and is working for password authentication.

Comment: Does this ldapsearch works on the command line? If you get no results, the query would be bad, if only attribute was missing, you would at the very least get entry DN as a result.